# Al generar la APK de mi proyecto Android, lo genera sin base de datos SQLite

Tags: sqlite, apk

Al generar la APK de mi proyecto Android, logro generarlo sin errores y logro instalarlo sin problemas en mi dispositivo, pero la base de datos que en mi proyecto funciona con SQLite y en simulacion corre normal, en la App instalada aparece vacia.

¿Que debo hacer?.

Debo incluir la base de datos dentro de alguna carpeta interna de mi proyecto Android antes de generar la APK??

Ejemplo del codigo que tengo en un Fragment donde invoco la base de datos y funciona normal en la simulacion pero en APK no aparece:

```
ConexionSQLHelper conn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resistencia_ppal);

    conn = new ConexionSQLHelper(getApplicationContext(), "bd_hpc_users", null, 1);
    listaResistencias = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerResistencia = findViewById(R.id.rv_resistencia_lista);
    recyclerResistencia.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    svSearchNombreResistencia = findViewById(R.id.svSearchNombreReistencia);
    svSearchNombreResistencia.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    consultaListaResistencias();
    adaptadorRes = new AdapterResistencia(listaResistencias, this);
    recyclerResistencia.setAdapter(adaptadorRes);

}

private void consultaListaResistencias() {
    if(svSearchNombreResistencia != null){
        listaResistencias = new ArrayList<Resistencia>();
        Cursor cursor = conn.getData("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_RESISTENCIA+ " ORDER BY "+ Utilidades.CAMPO_RESISTENCIA_AREA);
        listaResistencias.clear();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String planta = cursor.getString(1);
            String area = cursor.getString(2);
            String linea = cursor.getString(3);
            String sistema = cursor.getString(4);
            String descripcion = cursor.getString(5);
            String forma = cursor.getString(6);
            String diametro = cursor.getString(7);
            String largo = cursor.getString(8);
            String voltaje = cursor.getString(9);
            String potencia = cursor.getString(10);
            String codigo = cursor.getString(11);


            listaResistencias.add(new Resistencia(null, planta, area, linea, sistema, descripcion, forma, diametro, largo, voltaje, potencia, codigo));

        }recyclerResistencia.setAdapter(adaptadorRes);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // listaRepuestos = new ArrayList<>();
        // AdapterRepuesto adaptador = new AdapterRepuesto(listaRepuestos, this);
        // recyclerRepuestos.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String r) {
    adaptadorRes.filtrarResistenciaNombre(r);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

}
```

}

Comment: Debes precargar la base de datos, poniéndola preferiblemente dentro del directorio `assets`. [Revisa la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate?hl=es-419) al respecto.